# Item filter button appearing briefly

Tags: dspace

I'm researching institutional repositories.  I have found that with some DSpace instances, when loading the response to a blank search (i.e. all), the filter bars very briefly include a Type selector, which disappears as the page loads fully.  For example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0J5x.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kx3SJ.png)

Some retain the selector, but quite a few display similar behaviour (both on Chromium and Firefox on Ubuntu).  Does anyone have any explanation for it, either technical or policy-wise?

Answer (score 0):

This filter relates to the "Entity" feature. I can only be sure if you would report the specific DSpace 7 minor version, but my guess would be that in the instances where you see this, the filter would disappear if there are no specific entities configured, e.g. if everything is rendering as the same entity.

More on DSpace 7 Entities:
https://wiki.lyrasis.org/display/DSDOC7x/Configurable+Entities